# How to filter recurring triplets from this Pythagorean triplet code?

Tags: c

I wrote below code but it gives output repeated. Such as 3,4,5 and 4,5,3 and 5,4,3. It     shows the same triplet. How can I prevent this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

int side1=1;
int side2=1;
int hypotenus=1;
int till;
int count=0;

printf("Till what number do you want to find triplets?");
scanf("%d",&till);  

for(side1=1;side1<=till;side1++){

    for(side2=1;side2<=till;side2++){

        for(hypotenus=1;hypotenus<=till;hypotenus++){

            if(hypotenus*hypotenus==side1*side1+side2*side2){

                count++;
                printf("%5d %5d %5d is a triple \n",side1,side2,hypotenus);
            }
        }

    }

}
printf("\n");
printf("%d triplets found.",count);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: I'd be surprised to see this program produce "4,5,3 and 5,4,3" as outputs.  The value of `hypotenus` couldn't be smaller than `side` or `side2`.

Comment: You are right I just gave them as example. It only gives 3 4 5 and 4 3 5. Not the third one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
for(side2=side1;side2<=till;side2++){
```

i.e change the start value of this cycle. This way you will only find triplets where side2>=side1 and will never count both a triplet of the type `(side1, side2, hyp)` and a triplet of the type `(side2, side1, hyp)`